# PyQt5: How to pass a variable to a class?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am building a small utility in pyqt5 and try to pass a variable into another class ui file.

main ui file

```
self.showError(errorMessage)
```

how do I pass "errorMessage" into this class? Should I pass like this? 
class Ui_Error(object, errorMessage):

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Error(object):
    def setupUi(self, Error):
        Error.setObjectName("Error")
        Error.resize(577, 245)
        Error.setModal(True)
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(Error)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 20, 521, 151))
        self.textBrowser.setOverwriteMode(False)
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Error)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 190, 161, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.retranslateUi(Error)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(Error.close)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Error)

    def retranslateUi(self, Error):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Error.setWindowTitle(_translate("Error", "Error"))
        self.textBrowser.setHtml(_translate("Error", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:16pt;\">" + errorMessage + "</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Error", "Close"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Error = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Error()
    ui.setupUi(Error)
    Error.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set your class (in this case `Ui_Error`) up to accept parameters when initialized. that is accomplished through the class' `__init__` function. So your class should be declared like this:

```
class Ui_Error:
    def __init__(self, object, error_message):
        # Whatever you want to do with object and error_message
```

You can get more info on classes [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).

Comment: awesome. I forgot I cannot pass a variable into a class, but require a constructor.